# How to Import data from csv to couchbase Lite

Tags: android, ios, couchbase, couchbase-lite, nosql

How to Import data from csv to couchbase Lite, Our app does not update/delete/insert data. We are only SELECT data from the Couchbase database.

We already have data in CSV, now we want to import the data from CSV to Couachbase Lite.

Thanks and regards,
Sheetal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in functionality for this, you will need to write this functionality yourself and it's too broad to write in one answer but the parts would be:

1) Parse a line of CSV
2) Determine how to construct it into JSON
3) Insert that JSON into the DB via `Document.PutProperties`